# How I can set a value to a List in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

In the following loop how may I create a new List<>(), but I have a problem in the moment I try to set a value:

ListlistOfString = new ArrayList()<>;
listOfString.set(index, value);

Can anyone explain me how does it work?

Comment: You can only assign values to *variables* but methods return *values* not *variables. Even if you have method like `int x = 1;  int getX(){ return x;}` and you try to invoke `getX()` it will return value `2` not *variable* not variable `x`. That is the problem with `announcementDTO.get(j) = new ArrayList<>();` and `announcementResultBean.get(i) = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: and how can I do to resolve it @Pshemo?

Comment: You can use `list.set(index, newValue)`.

Comment: It did't work @Pshemo, now the error is: The method set(int, announcementDTO) in the type List<announcementDTO> is not applicable for the arguments (int, new ArrayList<>())

Comment: If your list declared as `List<announcementDTO>` then it means it is supposed to hold only `announcementDTO` instances (or its subtypes). Why would you want to place `ArrayList` there? It is like trying to place a `cat` in box with `dog`s...

Comment: Now after reading your code I see that `announcementDTO` is new can *empty* list so `set` can't be used yet. First you need to *add* new elements to list. We can use `set(index, newVlaue)` when we want to *replace* old value at that index with new one, but value at that index first need to exist (in other words `index` which can be used in `set` must be smaller than list `size()`). So again, to fill array with new data you can use `list.add(newElement)` which ill place `newElement` after currently last element (or at start if list was empty).

Comment: In your efforts to get this question re-opened you have now made your question much worse by now not providing the required details please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , bring back the code you have removed and give the actual error's coming from the Compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike arrays, you cannot do `array[i] = val`. You should use [`ArrayList.set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-):

```java
// this must be set
announcementDTO.set(j, new ArrayList<>());
// this can still be get
announcementDTO.get(j).setIdShop(shopBean.getId());
announcementDTO.get(j).setNombreComercio(comercioBean.getNombre());
announcementDTO.get(j).setRazonSocial(comercioBean.getRazonSocial());
```

Comment: It did't work @Aplet123, now the error is: The method set(int, announcementDTO) in the type List<announcementDTO> is not applicable for the arguments (int, new ArrayList<>())

Comment: @Gonzalo That's because you delcare `announcementDTO` as `List<AnnouncementDTO>` instead of `List<List<AnnouncementDTO>>` or `List<ArrayList<AnnouncementDTO>>`.

Comment: oh, this is hard to undestand, but I try @Aplet123

Comment: Hi @Aplet just one question, the original code is announcementDTO[j] = new announcementDTO(); and I have to work now just with List, not arrays. What do you think?

Comment: @Gonzalo I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: oh, before this code was made with Arrays, and now, I have to convert the arrays into Lists. So the original line of code was: announcementDTO[j] = new AnnouncementDTO();  How can I solve it with Lists?

Comment: Like I outlined in my answer: `announcementDTO.set(j, new AnnouncementDTO())`. `array[i] = v` is replaced by `arraylist.set(i, v)`.

Comment: @Gonzalo Note that `set` is used to *replace existing* element in list. If list is empty there is no element to be replaced. If you want to fill array with new elements you need to use `add` method.